# SELECT * FROM table WHERE (my_id) IN table_column (assigned_id)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `tasks` Where has a column named `assigned_id` which has comma separated values like (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). I need to count of the tasks user has assigned.

In Example: My name is Imdad and my `user_id` is `5`, and the `tasks` table has column `assigned_id` which values are like `1, 3, 4, 5, 7...` I need to count all the number of rows which `assigned_id` contain my `user_id` which is `5`.

I have tried so many methods but not working till now.

I have tried

`SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE $user_id IN (assigned_id);`
Here the **user_id** is **5**

It's returning if the `assign_id` value start with **5** (Example: 5, 3, 6, 7...)

Here is my code

```
<?php
$data = "SELECT COUNT('1') FROM task WHERE $user[id] IN (assigned_id)";
$get_data = mysqli_query($conn, $data);
$show = mysqli_fetch_array($get_data);
echo $show[0];
?>
```

I am attaching a screenshot for better understand!!!

Here I have marked the data which I want
[image: Here I have marked the data which I want]

But Here is the image with query, I got the first value
[image: Here is the image with query, I got the first value]

Comment: This looks like a bad DB design, you shouldn´t have comma separated values in the assigned_id. Anywais, you could try to use like, _WHERE assigned_id like '%$user[id]%'_ but you will have problems if you have two ids like 1, 10 and you look for id 1, you will get both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case you can use `find_in_set` function like:

```
select * 
from tbl
where find_in_set(5, assigned_id);
```

[SQL online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/94ef783fca9de6bc541ea47844e0fdea/)

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding on the above query this should work for you in MYSQL

if you want to get based on task_title

```
Select count(*) from tasks where assignee_id LIKE (CONCAT('%', (Select id from tasks where task_title = 'Imdad' LIMIT 1), '%'));
```

if you want to get based on id

```
Select count(*) from tasks where assignee_id LIKE (CONCAT('%', (Select id from tasks where id = 5 LIMIT 1), '%'));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's working but when the id is like 55 it's showing that also, It's because of %LIKE%!